# C# - looking for Better Intellisence / Autocomplete tool for VS2010 pro - more like JAVA Eclipce

Tags: c#, intellisense

I am comming from java and I am missing some staff in VS2010 Pro.

1. In java, when you type in a variable like:

   MyObject myObject;

Eclipse will let you automatically choose this names:

`myObject` or `object`

1. in eclipce you can generate entire class/bean just from the constructor.
2. variable refactor.
3. Good variable naming when refactoring to method.

VS 2010 intellisense is very limited, is there a tool /free/paid that can provide more features?

Thanks

Comment: Resharper is awesome, I use it.  There is also code rush.  Links:[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) [Code Rush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

This tool has been created by [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/index.html) that it is the same company that created the powerfull [IntelliJIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDE for Java. If you already used IntelliJIDEA you can use the same shortcuts in ReSharper.

This is a commercial tool but for my opinion it is indispensable.

Answer (score 1):

I am using DevEpxress CodeRush with Refactor Pro and i think its a great tool.Please have  a look and give it a try.They have a free version too.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/index.xml